# Is there a better way to organize this dynamic class naming?

Tags: javascript, css, sass, jsx

I have a variable `extend` which could be either an empty string `''` or `active`, which is a CSS class.

Once the top div is clicked, all subsequent elements updates with "active"

```
<div
      className={`container ${extend ? "active" : ""}`}
      onClick={() => setExtend(!extend)}
    >
      <p className={`card ${extend ? "active" : ""}`}>Visa Card</p>
      <h1 className={`balance ${extend ? "active" : ""}`}>$55,343.15</h1>
</div>
```

then my CSS looks like this

```
.container {
&.active
}

.card {
&.active
}

.balance {
&.active
}
```

I feel like there is a lot of repetition in both CSS and JS and I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this

Answer (score 1):

For your JS:

```
// Use a function to help init classes with active state if needed
const addClasses = useCallback((baseClasses) => {
  const classes = [baseClass];

  if (extend) {
    classes.push('active');
  }
 return classes.join(' ');
}, [extend]);

return  <div
      className={addClasses('container')}
      onClick={() => setExtend(!extend)}
    >
      <p className={addClasses('container')}>Visa Card</p>
      <h1 className={addClasses('balance')}>$55,343.15</h1>
```

For your CSS, it depends on what you're doing in &.active. If each of them have the same active style then:

For your CSS:

```
.container, .card, .balance {
  &.active {
    // common style goes here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good idea in your case may be use `classnames` package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames. By this you can easily manage class names of your components.